# How to remove empty columns in transaction data read with the arules package?

Tags: r, transactions, arules

I have a dataset made in the format of a basket data. I have read that dataset in R using a package call [arules](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/arules.pdf) which has an inbuilt function for reading transactions, so I have used that and read my dataset. Following is the code I used:

```
trans = read.transactions("C:/Users/HARI/Desktop/Graph_mining/transactional_data_v3.csv", format = "basket", sep=",",rm.duplicates=TRUE)
inspect(trans[1:5])
  items                  
1 {,                     
   ANTIVERT,             
   SOFTCLIX}             
2 {,                     
   CEFADROXIL,           
   ESTROGEN}             
3 {,                     
   BENZAMYCIN,           
   BETAMETH,             
   KEFLEX,               
   PERCOCET}             
4 {,                     
   ACCUTANE(RXPAK;10X10),
   BENZAMYCIN}           
5 {,                     
   ALBUTEROL,            
   BUTISOLSODIUM,        
   CLARITIN,             
   NASACORTAQ}
```

As you can see, when I use `inspect(trans)` it shows transactions with an empty column in each. My question is how can I remove those empty columns?

For a full `dput` of the `trans` object, please see [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxE3rA3-6F8eOGdWaHlOR0ZEZXc/view).

Comment: They are packages, not libraries. Please post `dput(trans)`

Comment: `"14834", "14835", "14836"), class = "AsIs")), .Names = "itemsetID", row.names = c(NA, 
-14836L), class = "data.frame")
)`                                    This what i get after `dput(trans)`

Comment: Your dput is truncated... can you pls add it fully into the body of your question?

Comment: dput doesn't show full in my rstudio its shows from 7000. How can i get the full dput? @DominicComtois

Comment: you can `dput(head(trans, 20))` for 20 first lines for instance

Comment: can you post `trans@itemInfo` ? You probably have a blank item.

Comment: @DominicComtois I have attached dput(head(trans,20)) in the body

Comment: @NealFultz When i use `trans@itemInfo` it has a list of 3778 items

Comment: Something odd with the dput text... usually starts with `structure(list(...`, not sure why in this case it doesn't. And it's giving errors (there are '...' and other irregularities in it. Can you try with 5 lines only? (`dput(head(trans))`)

Comment: @DominicComtois following is the link for whole dput file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxE3rA3-6F8eOGdWaHlOR0ZEZXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Harish Ok I got it now. I'd have a few questions but it would be better to move to chat if you wish... Not sure how to do it, usually we get a prompt for it after a few messages but I haven't gotten one yet.

Comment: @Harish It seems we have to wait for the prompt to do so. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96247/is-it-possible-to-import-comments-into-a-chat-room-without-the-link-appearing

Comment: @DominicComtois sir can we have chat in any other way possible

Comment: @DominicComtois Sir actually the dataset which i made has 14836 rows and 38 columns but in the `dput` it shows 3778 rows and 6 columns after i import the file using `read.transaction` function from arules package.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was curious, if you could put the csv instead of the transaction object on the google page there...

Comment: @DominicComtois Sir following is the link for the csv file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxE3rA3-6F8eSUJ3QXk0RjJZNUk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've found a solution to your problem. I took your csv file, opened it in Excel and replaced all empty cells with NA. Then I pasted the whole thing into LibreOffice Calc and saved it back to csv specifying that double quotes should be used for all cells (oddly enough, Excel won't do that except with a vba macro. You could read the file directly in LibreOffice instead of Excel, however, replacing empty cells with NA's will take forever). Then:

```
trans <- read.table("d:/downloads/transactional_data_2.csv", sep=",", stringsAsFactors = TRUE, na.strings="NA", header=TRUE)
trans2 <- as(trans, "transactions")
inspect(trans2[1:5])
```

**RESULTS**

```
inspect(trans[1:5])

  items                      transactionID
1 {X1=SOFTCLIX,                           
   X2=ANTIVERT}                          1
2 {X1=ESTROGEN,                           
   X2=CEFADROXIL}                        2
3 {X1=KEFLEX,                             
   X2=BETAMETH,                           
   X3=PERCOCET,                           
   X4=BENZAMYCIN}                        3
4 {X1=BENZAMYCIN,                         
   X2=ACCUTANE(RXPAK;10X10)}             4
5 {X1=CLARITIN,                           
   X2=ALBUTEROL,                          
   X3=NASACORTAQ,                         
   X4=BUTISOLSODIUM}                     5
```

I think that's the results you're looking for...?

Comment: It seems Neal had the proper solution in the end... so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your answer but i need transactions without X1 and X2. what i mean is i want transaction in this way `1 {SOFTCLIX, ANTIVERT}` and i dont want tansaction id too. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not super familiar with the arules package. My best guess is to read in the data using `read.csv` and then convert to transaction format instead of using the provided `read.transactions`:

```
tran2 <- read.csv("downloads/transactional_data.csv")
tran3 <- as(tran2, "transactions")
```

EDIT: I believe that the blanks in your data are not being read in correctly; additionally, there are duplicates which should also be filtered out. This should deal with that. You will need the `reshape2` package.

```
trans2 <- read.csv("downloads/transactional_data.csv", na.strings="", stringsAsFactors=FALSE )
trans2$id <- seq(nrow(trans2))
t2.long <- melt(trans2, id.vars="id")
t2.long$variable <- NULL
t3 <- as(lapply(split(t2.long$value, t2.long$id), unique), "transactions")
```

Comment: This is the error which i get when i execute your code. `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.0 Gb In addition: Warning messages:
1: In unique.default(.Internal(unlist(lapply(x, levels), recursive,  :
  Reached total allocation of 2932Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In unique.default(.Internal(unlist(lapply(x, levels), recursive,  :
  Reached total allocation of 2932Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In unique.default(.Internal(unlist(lapply(x, levels), recursive,  :
  Reached total allocation of 2932Mb: see help(memory.size)`

Comment: I didn't get those error messages. Can you try `memory.limit(NA)` before running it again?

Comment: @DominicComtois This is what i get when i use  `memory.limit(NA)
[1] 2932`